# Subdomain Bruteforcing when every request gets resolved?

Tags: sub-domain, enumeration

Is it possible for an attacker to get a list of the subdomains configured for my server, if every subdomain request gets resolved?

In the case of a subdomain that doesn't exist, the server simply resolves to a standard page. In my case it is the "Webserver Default Page" provided by Parallels Plesk.

Comment: if the crawler is configured to disregard the default text, then crawlers can certainly enumerate your subdomains because their content is different

Comment: @schroeder But wouldn`t this be seen as a DDos attack in some way by the server/hoster and could be prevented by establishing certain DDos protection tools ? (In contrast to just crawling DNS Records and not directly connecting to the page/server itself)

Comment: It depends on the speed and methods of the crawling

Answer (score 1):

As Schroeder stated, if the crawler is configured to not hammer your server with requests, it could most certainly enumerate each subdomain. If this is for hiding something like an admin panel, you would be best off relying on a secure login system rather than obscuring the site as you don't want to rely on security by obscurity.